# Plotting the vectors for correspoding index in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I have two vectors `A = [12 21 23 14 15 36 63 63 .... ]` ( of 100 values ) and another vector `B = [1:1:100]`.

Now i want to plot a bar graph such that i can plot the values of A on Y axis for corresponding value from B vector on X -axis. E.g. to plot 12 for 1, 21 for 2 , 23 for 3 and so on.

I tried doing `hist(A,B)` but it did not work. Let me know some another approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to use a regular bar plot:

```
>> bar(B,A)
```

If you have too many values on the x-axis, this might produce a nicer plot:

```
B = 1:100;
A = randi(100,size(B));

bar(B,A,'histc');
xlim([1 100])
```

[image: bar_plot]

Comment: Done !! Thanks a lot for helping such a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

```
hist(A,100)
```

produces a histogram of A, the second parameter is the number of bins that you want. There's some [examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) in the documentation

Comment: `hist` will perform binning. From what I understood, the OP simply wants to plot y-values against x-values using bars instead of lines and points

Comment: yes, rereading I think you are right. `hist(A,100)` is what the OP should have used instead of `hist(A,B)`